# SSIS onerror event. Execute SQL task just sits there

Tags: ssis

I have an execute sql task that executes within the package level onerror event.  The task will run just fine if it's not within the onerror event, however, if it's sitting in the flow for the onerror event, it just turns yellow, and does nothing.

I have a file task that will complete just fine as well within the onerror event.

SSIS 2008 R2

Thanks,

Comment: It inserts some error records into a table for me.

Comment: There is actually a series of events (send an email, move some files, run a stored procedure, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the OnTaskFailed handler instead.  That seemed to fit my requirements as much as the OnError event.